# Как заполнить абстрактный метод в Java

Tags: java, ооп

Есть 2 класса

Класс B

```
public B{
  public void onStart() {
Тут какая логика в виде for
    }
}
```

Класс A

```
public A extend B{

}
```

Теперь IDE должен подчеркнуть красным `public A extend B` И сказать что надо объязательно добавить метод `onStart` и всю его реализуцию тоже.

Я такое видео в некоторых библиотеках. Что мне сделать чтобы добиться этого.
Абстрактные методы и класс использовать не получится, потому что метод в абстракте не реализованный а лишь шаблонный.

Может использовать аннотации? интерфесы? есть что нибудь такое в Java?

Comment: Создавай наследника от абстрактного класса и переопределяй тот метод или сразу у абстрактного класса определи тот метод, сделав его обычным, без abstract

Comment: слово `abstract` из описания метода уберите

Comment: @rjhdby, Я изменил описание, думаю сейчас более менее понятно в чем моя проблема

Comment: Взаимоисключающие требования вижу я. С одной стороны вы хотите, чтобы использовался код метода родителя, а с другой желаете требования реализовавыть его в потомке. Вы сами сначала определитесь, чего же хотите на самом деле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Абстрактный метод – это метод без тела (без реализации). При объявлении абстрактного метода можно определить только его сигнатуру.

Исходя из вышесказанного, Ваш код:

```
public abstract void onMes() {
    swtch(adas){
    case 1: break;
    }
}
```

не скомпилируется.

> Чтобы наследуемые классы автоматически получили этот метод

Для этого Вам нужен обычный метод (с реализацией), а не абстрактный.

При объявлении метода таким образом:

```
public void onMes() {
    swtch(adas){
    case 1: break;
    }
}
```

во всех классах, наследуемых от класса с этим методом, этот метод будет доступен (с условием того, что в сабклассах он не переопределен).

Comment: @EraNewGames, `А при создании обычного метода ничего не происходит` – а нужно, чтобы что-то происходило? Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос яснее.